# Whats the most optimal way to handle multiple Root CA Certificates in ESP32 code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, esp32, arduino-esp32

Looking for best practice how to handle (in code) scenario where I have ESP32 which can connect to 5 different HTTPS endpoints, each signed by different RootCA.

The flow is as follows:

1. The ESP32 wakes up from deep sleep
2. Based on some (unrelated to the question) logic it determines it needs to connect to one of the 5 endpoints
3. It uses HTTPClient and WiFiClientSecure to connect. In order to make the connection it needs to call wiFiClient.setCACert(char* rootCA); and then make the call.
4. Once it finishes the call it goes into deep sleep and the cycle repeats on next restart

Right now I am storing the root certificate in const char* rootCA for each endpoint and depending on which one I need to connect to I am passing that one to the setCACert method, but it seems to me I am wasting a lot of memory on storing 5 char arrays since at any given boot I will only use 1 of the 5.

Is there a best practice to store the certs in some kind of static text file and then load the correct one when needed? Would this consume less memory than storing 5 long char arrays?

I'm using Visual Studio Pro 2022 with Visual Micro plug-in if that matters.

Comment: Does it matter? Are you short on memory?

Comment: Not yet, just looking for best practice.  Also I am more concerned about battery impact since the device will be LiPo powered and I want to make sure I optimize the code to finish each boot cycle as efficiently as possible. TBH thought I don't think 5 char arrays in the memory would impact power consumption significantly, unless I am wrong?

Comment: There's no reason character arrays in memory would use more power.